# How to get POSTGRES DB name along with table names through python code / Bash?

Tags: bash, python-2.7, postgresql

I want to get Postgres DB names along with the table names through the python code / BASH scripting.

Comment: If you're already scripting in python, what's the use of bash here? Do you need python to output name/value pairs for variables that bash can source?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Through bash I got the results. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can list all database names with:

```
psql -A -t -c 'SELECT datname FROM pg_database'
```

and you can list all tables from `information_schema.tables`, e.g.:

```
psql -A -t -F $'\t' -d my_database -c 'SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables`
```

NOTE: The information schema is database specific.

Comment: `psql -X -q -c "copy (select datname from pg_database) to stdout"` to avoid unwanted additional info in the output.

Comment: You can achieve the same effect just with the command line parameters `-A ` and `-t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
LGREEN='\033[1;32m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
#echo -e " ${YELLOW}RepoList${NC} Updating "

echo "********************** % Viki % ************************"
echo " "
echo " "
echo " "
echo -e " ${LGREEN} Note: Type ${YELLOW} \l ${LGREEN} to list db names and ${YELLOW} ctrl+z ${LGREEN} to close the name"
echo " "
echo " "
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
echo " "
echo " ${YELLOW} **********************  POSTGRES DB NAME ************************"
echo " "
exec bash
```

> Created by myself. Thanks for the help.